# Intregrating Media-7.x-1.5 Module in CKEditor 4.4.3 (7.x-1.16) with Picture Module

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I am not able to upload image with picture tag inside CKEditor.When i upload image,media automatically defaults it to mobile image(lowest in the picture mapping) in the picture group without showing the rest of the source(i have selected the view mode with picture).Rest of the images without picture tag are output correctly.

Also "Convert Media tags to markup" - enabling or disabling it in the Text Format in the configuration doesn't have any effect.What changes should I make in the configuration to get [picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) module work with [Ck editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) using [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module?